# Hot swap port mappings on docker containers

Tags: docker

I have an application that exposes a binary-protocol over a TCP port.  I am looking into moving over to docker but there is one issue which I am encountering.  Currently, I have a mechanism for upgrading a server without dropping the connection.  I am able to upgrade the server by basically handing over the port to the new application instance.  I can build a layer like this based on docker, but I'm wondering if there is instead a way of using docker to hand over port connections from one container to another.  I was hoping that I could just start a new container with the same port and it would just magically work.  Sadly, you apparently are not permitted to attach to a port that is already mapped.

Is there a way to do this?  Or do I need to construct a proxy layer of some sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend going the proxy route since it will make things a lot easier to dynamically add and remove your containers. That said, you can create a new container with another container's network namespace using `--net container:name`. You'll have the same IP and even see the same connections:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
13062f97a75c        registry:2          "/bin/registry serve "   11 weeks ago        Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry

$ docker run -it --rm --net container:registry debian

root@13062f97a75c:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 20:22 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash
root         7     1  0 20:22 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef

root@13062f97a75c:/# apt-get update && apt-get install net-tools
...

root@13062f97a75c:/# netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Interesting... how does that even work? Can they both bind to the same port? Would I need to use SOREUSEPORT?

Comment: It puts the network for each container in the same namespace. So you're on the identical network interface. Whatever you can do to reuse the port between processes outside of the container will hopefully work inside the container too.